# Pell type equation about prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, pell-type-equations

Let $p=4k+1$ be a prime number such that $p=a^2+b^2$ , with $a$ an odd integer. Prove that the equation $$x^2-py^2=a$$ has at least a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Only a little progress (maybe useless): for any prime divisor $q$ of $a$, we get $(\frac{q}{p})=1$ through Guass' quadratic reciprocity law, which suggests $(\frac{a}{p})=1$.

Comment: that's a good one. Where did you get it?

Comment: @WillJagy From my classmate.